# Can I apply for a US tourist visa from any Indian consulate, or just from the one that's tied to my home state?

Tags: visas, usa, india

I live in Gujarat. When applying for a visa interview from the site https://cgifederal.secure.force.com/, it asks me for my state of residence. On selecting Gujarat, it assigns me to the Mumbai consulate. The issue is that the wait time at the Mumbai consulate is atleast a month more than the wait time at the Hyderabad consulate. If I choose my state of residence as Telangana/Orissa to get assigned to the Hyderabad consulate, will it be considered invalid?

Comment: Where did you get this website from ? The only place you could trust is a US embassy website in India, please go here and follow the appointment link https://hyderabad.usconsulate.gov/visaservices.html

Comment: @blackbird57 That _is_ the official web site.

Comment: Another fine example of the US Government causing confusing and making fraud easier by using random non-official domains for official purposes. This makes it easier for scammers to lure unsuspecting people, since not even the official stuff is on official government domains. In this case, CGI Federal is a major government IT contractor, and force.com is Salesforce's cloud hosting system.

Comment: @ZachLipton - The US uses 3rd party services in many countries to help with the massive load of visa inquiries it gets every day.  All of these third parties have "non-official" domains, because they are not government agencies, but private contractors. But all are linked to from the visa information pages on the embassy and consulate websites.  You can't blame the government if the traveler is too lazy to look up details on the embassy website and instead simply believes the first "get your US visa" website shown on the search results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each consulate services a fixed geographical area and people from that state are only eligible to have their visa screening done through the respective consulate. This is done to prevent abuse and fraud.

If you change your address to somewhere you don't actually stay, the following may occur:

1. The visa officer may ask your current residence and why it doesn't coincide with your paperwork. Unsatisfactory answers may result in rejection of your petition.
2. If approved, your passport may be sent to the address in Telangana / Orissa if not being picked up at the consulate.
3. If the visa officer decided that you are committing fraud, he / she may place additional sanctions on your file thus making any petitions in future harder or impossible to get approved. It is highly advisable to present your visa petition case as honestly as you can.

If for some reason, you cannot wait till the next available date for your visa interview, then you can request for an emergency interview. Emergency requests are granted outside of the normal interview slots and are granted on a per-case basis. Emergency can be anything ranging from death of an immediate family member, job reporting date drawing near, etc. Be prepared to explain in detail about the nature of your emergency request.